# How can I reduce the time complexity of a nested loop algorithm? My example pseudocode is attached below

Tags: loops, optimization, nested

Please advise on how to reduce the time complexity of the below 2 while loops if there is any possibility.

```
function printing_s(n,s){
    i=1
    while(i<=n){
       j=1
       while(j<=i){
          print(s)
          j=2*j
       }
       i=i+1
    }
}
```

Comment: It helps to explain what the loops should do.

Comment: run `print(s)` 11 times and remove the rest of the code. There, complexity reduced :)

Comment: if the n is a variable how can the complexity be reduced. I'm sorry I had a typing mistake before. n is passed in to the function. Thanks